# Create plot with large text file in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, txt

I want to recreate a plot in Python from a dataset that looks like the figure below.
It has four columns (time1, power1, time2, power2), tab delimiters and contains about 5000 rows.
[Text file with data](https://file.io/Dem2fGXhEG7j)

It should look like the following;

[image]

Instead it looks like this in Python;
[image]

Obviously I am making mistakes. I am quite new to python so it might be a dumb fault. My code is as follows;

```
# Import
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Load data from csv file
Filename = "powercurveHTC10000_2.txt"

with open(Filename) as inp:
 Dataoverview = list(zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in inp)))
 print(list(zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in inp))) )

 #Data1 = Dataoverview[1]

 Time1 = Dataoverview[0][0:5000]
 Power1 = Dataoverview[1][0:5000]
 Time2 = Dataoverview[3][0:5000]
 Power2 = Dataoverview[4][0:5000]

 print('probeer', Dataoverview[3][0:2])

 # Plot
 plt.plot(Time1, Power1, 'ro')
 # plt.plot(Time2, Power2, 'b*')
 plt.title('Power usage measured by thermocouples')
 plt.ylim(0,100)
 plt.xlim(3000,4250)
 plt.gca().set_xticks([2])
 plt.gca().set_yticks([2])
 plt.xlabel('Cycles [s]')
 plt.ylabel('Power [W]')
 plt.show()
```

Love to heat what I did wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please supply a sample of the data so we can copy it. Image is no good. Or a link to the data if online.

Comment: When you read data from a file like this, it comes in as strings.  You possibly just need to convert the strings to floats.  This is a common mistake: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Comment: You could also have a look at numpy.loadtxt https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 1):

I see you're importing pandas in your code but not using it.
Have you tried something like this?

```
df = pd.read_csv('powercurveHTC10000_2.txt', delimiter="    ")
df.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Probably `delimiter="    "` should be changed to `delim_whitespace=True`? That should also take care of tab characters (which seem to be used by the original post).